# Removing the text from the automated back button on a navigation controller

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, back-button

I'm sure this was covered before but I can't find exactly what I'm after. I'm using a custom image for the back button on my navigation controller and need to remove the text, is there a simple way of doing this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The text overlays itself on my arrow image

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the back button as follows:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = 
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-arrow.png"]
                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                       target:self
                                       action:@selector(backButtonPressed:)];


self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = @"";
```